# Find image path to GCE image

Tags: google-compute-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

When configuring a gitlab runner I can tell it what type of instances to spawn on GCP via the google-machine-image keyword.

How do I find out what the path to an GCE image is?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the URIs running the following command:

```
$ gcloud compute images list --uri
```

[Here's](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list) is more information about it.